# Isn't exception Drawback of Callable interface?

Tags: java, multithreading, callable

1. Why is that we need FutureTask instance when we make thread using callable?

2.I could see that, Using callbale we can get the exception(if occured), using futuretask.get() method. SO in that case, our Main thread should be waiting till the thread is completed!. Will it not destroy the soul purpose of threading? Is it not a drawback of Callable?

Answer (score 1):

```
V get() throws InterruptedException,ExecutionException
```

> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves
>   its result.

Now

> Why is that we need FutureTask instance when we make thread using
>   callable?

If you need the result of callable then you should use it

> our Main thread should be waiting till the thread is completed!

Yes So until and unless you really need the result you should avoid using it

You can also use [overloaded version](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) So that wait will not be `infinite` and you get Timeout Exception as soon as `wait()` timed out

Answer (score 0):

The answers:

1. **You don't need `FutureTask`, you can pass the `Callable` to `ExecutorService.submit()`**.
2. **The `get()` method is designed to be blocking and it's not the problem.** The idea is to execute the functionality in background and meanwhile you can execute other code, you can pass the `FutureTask` to some other method, etc.
3. **It's important that `Callable.call()` throws `Exception`.** If you look at the "standard" `Runnable` it does not throw any checked exception, so in the case of error handling you have to put the exception handling logic in the `run()` just to compile your program.